# Using Construct tools to construct a feature from line to polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

Is it possible for me to build a construct a line to polygon? For example, when you need a break or divide one polygon into two polygons. You had the line from a polygon to Line and you use that line to construct the feature that polygon to break two.

Currently, I tried to use this method using the Advanced Editing and when you selected two features: one line and one polygon even though the icon on the Advanced Editing shows no grayscale.

Is there a way around to do this ? It would save A Lot of time to use the "Cut Polygons" or any other tools.

Revised to explain more in detail.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. There is a Feature to Polygon tool in Arc that will convert lines to polygons (assuming the lines close). Or are you looking to use existing lines to split existing polygons into two or more features?

Comment: I've use that feature to polygon tool in Arc. YEs I want to use the existing lines to split the existing polygons into two or more features.  Thanks for explaining clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Split tool under Advanced Editing Toolbar also. Please see attached file for reference.

[image]